# Scroll Gigantesco

Tags: html, css

Meu site está com um scroll enorme, ultrapassando o conteudo do site e mostrando um fundo branco.
Já tentei definir um max-height na tag `html` mas não mudou nada

http://www.angeltourbrasil.com.br

Comment: recomendo você utilizar bootstrap, vai poupar muito o seu tempo e fica bem melhor, pois ele já possui botões e etc sem contar na grid dele que já e responsiva para mobile desktop, como você está fazendo algo para algum negócio, ainda mais de praia é provável que muitas pessoas irão acessar pelo celular, e será necessário você ter um site responsivo me entende, recomendo muito você aprender :D [Bootstrap framework em português](http://getbootstrap.com.br/getting-started/) [Curso bootstrap em português](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLd4yfya-3PIomj2O-W0s9A-0i1ThWJncj)

Answer (score 1):

Tenta trabalhar em cima da ideia de colocar o seguinte estilo no seu site:

```
#galeria {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Suas fotos estão vazando!

Answer (score 0):

Teu problema está nas tuas divs class="lbox"
Se tu usar o inspetor do navegador vai ver que essas divs todas "caem" do teu layout.
Revisa o css dessa parte aí.